# How can I make custom options for each sub category, like Amazon in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**This is my data structure**

```
categories (collection)
|
--- mainCategoryId (document)
    |
    --- mainCategoryName (field -> string) (value -> Cars)
    --- image (field -> string) (value -> https://...)
    --- numberOfPosts (field -> number) (value -> 281)
    --- subCategories (sub-collection)
        |
        --- subCategoryId (document)
            |
            --- subCategoryName (field -> string) (value -> Cars For Sale)
            --- image (field -> string) (value -> https://...)
            --- numberOfPosts (field -> number) (value -> 81)
        --- subCategoryId (document)
            |
            --- subCategoryName (field -> string) (value -> Car Rental)
            --- image (field -> string) (value -> https://...)
            --- numberOfPosts (field -> number) (value -> 200)
```

**The custom options for this sub category (Cars For Sale)**

```
01- Car Make (Audi) (BMW) (Toyota) (Ford) (etc...)
02- Model -> Depending on car make for example Ford company (E-350) (F-150) (F-250) (F-350) (etc...)
03- Year (From) (To)
04- Price (From) (To)
05- Condition (Used) (New)
06- Kilometers (1 - 9,999) (10,000 - 19,999) (20,000 - 29,999) (30,000 - 39,999) (etc...)
07- Transmission (Automatic) (Manual)
08- Fuel (Gasoline) (Diesel) (Hybrid) (Electric) (etc...)
09- Car Options (Sunroof) (Electric Mirrors) (Touch Screen) (Keyless Entry) (etc...)
10- Car License (Licensed) (No Licensed)
11- Insurance (Compulsory Insurance) (Comprehensive Insurance) (Not Insured)
12- Color (Red) (Blue) (Yellow) (Green) (etc...)
13- Payment Method (Cash Only) (Installments Only) (Cash or Installments)
```

**The custom options for this sub category (Car Rental)**

```
01- Car Make (Audi) (BMW) (Toyota) (Ford) (etc...)
02- Model -> Depending on car make for example Ford company (E-350) (F-150) (F-250) (F-350) (etc...)
03- Year (From) (To)
04- Price (From) (To)
05- Transmission (Automatic) (Manual)
06- Fuel (Gasoline) (Diesel) (Hybrid) (Electric) (etc...)
07- Rental period (Daily) (Weekly) (Monthly) (Yearly)
08- Color (Red) (Blue) (Yellow) (Green) (etc...)
```

I have a search box, but it's not advanced. I want to improve it and make it working with customization, so I want to show options depending on sub category. But the problem is: How can I make these options in [Firestore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase#Firebase_Cloud_Firestore)? What is the best data structure to do this?

Comment: Your question is really not clear. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JayCodist I want to know what is the best way to save options above in Firestore

Comment: What's wrong with saving the options the way you already do?

Comment: @AlexMamo Should I create a field for every option inside the sub category or there is a better way?

Comment: I'm not aware of a better way. That's a quite common practice.

Comment: @Taha Can you refer to the link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data Is it helpful?